# How to delete empty deleted user home folder?

Tags: user-account, macos, administrator

I have a deleted user home folder in  the "Users" folder that does not contain anything and cannot be deleted. Can anybody suggest any ideas?

Comment: what machine do you have and what version of the system are you running?

Comment: I have a 2007 (I think, not sure) iMac, running on snow leopard

Comment: Open terminal. Enter ```ls -lO (drag the folder here)```. Paste the output here. There is probably a flag set like sappnd or schg that prevents you from deleting it.

Comment: If there is no flag present, then just ```rm -df``` it. If the directory is truly empty, then this should delete it.

Comment: Use ```sudo``` if you have permission errors.

Comment: It says that the directory is not empty whenever i try to delete it